# To use a third party email service for my own website or not

Tags: users, email

I have a very simple question. I am building a social networking website for people in the same profession as myself (Medical researcher). I want to send email notifications about threads posted on my site or other followed members activity. I'm coding the email functionality but I have to say, (i'm using PHPMailer), although my site may only have a max of 10-20k members in total, even sending off a few hundred emails in pretty slow. When does one move on to using a third party (if at all) like sendgrid? What experience do people have with this type of service dropped into their site?

Comment: Not sure this is a UX question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Extend the service at your current web hotel. If it can't be done, or if you find it too expensive then move to step...
2. Find another web hotel with a better service plan for e-mail services. Still not satisfied? Move to step # ...
3. Who reads e-mail in 2014? Really? Do you? Let's play with the thought that notifications can be made through other available services than an old SMTP-server. Did I hear you say App?

Comment: I have to agree with this answer. Especially if your focus is social, I think all the time and effort you intend to put into email could be put into improving your social stream.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. I do think that the cohort of users I am dealing with are essentially addicted to their email. Its the way our community interacts. Benny, what 'other' services do you mean? I would be very interested to learn.....

Comment: @GhostRider Addiction to e-mail is something very common. And if you really need e-mail notification, stick to it. But I think that e-mail isn't the best way to notify people. Maybe an App, SMS, flag or a simple tone is it. A notification is there to make a user aware of a change, not to convey the whole message...

Comment: what is a web hotel?

Comment: Also, *lots* of people still read email: http://www.forbes.com/sites/capitalonespark/2013/10/01/why-email-is-still-more-effective-than-social-media-marketing/